# Fastest way to get minimum data from Database

Tags: r, postgresql

I have a `Postgres` database. I want to find the minimum value of a column called `calendarid`, which is of type integer and the format `yyyymmdd`,  from a certain table. I am able to do so via the following code.

```
get_history_startdate <- function(src) {
  get_required_table(src) %>% # This gives me the table tbl(src, "table_name")
    select(calendarid) %>%
    as_data_frame %>%
    collect() %>%
    min() # Result : 20150131
}
```

But this method is really slow as it loads all the data from the database to the memory. Any ideas how can I improve it?

Comment: My approach will be to delegate the minimum finding task to the database. But I don't know how to do that. I will will appreciate any leads in this direction or any other better solution.

Comment: Maybe `get_required_table(src) %>% summarise(max(calendarid, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% pull`? It should run the appropriate SQL query. But anyway on most of the DBMS this query will be the one proposed by Tim Biegelseisen below.

Comment: @Scarabee This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't want to put explicit SQL queries into my code. I wanted the package to handle it. Can you please post it as an answer or that I can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get_required_table(src) %>% 
  summarise(max(calendarid, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  pull
```

will run the appropriate SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the minimum value of the `calendarid` column across the entire table, then use this:

```
SELECT MIN(calendarid) AS min_calendarid
FROM your_table;
```

I don't exactly what your R code is doing under the hood, but if it's bringing in the entire table from Postgres into R, then it is very wasteful.  If so, then running the above query directly on Postgres should give you a boost in performance.

Comment: I already thought of this approach. But in my opinion, sending an SQL query is creating a dependency on the database type. I wanted to handle it in R. To elaborate, I wanted R produce the same SQL query as mentioned by you under the hood. But I am a novice in R, I am not sure how to do that! I use `RPostgres` package to initialise the database and `DBI` package to connect to it.
As a last resort, I will construct a query as mentioned by you. But I want to explore any other elegant solutions. I read up a bit about `summary`, `slice` etc by the `dplyr` pkg. But couldn't wrap my head around it

Comment: You can't have it both ways.  Either you do the query on Postgres, which incurs some network latency and yes a dependency on the RDBMS, or you import all data, which uses even more network bandwidth and then takes up a bunch of memory in R.  R has libraries which let you fairly seamlessly execute queries on a SQL database.

Comment: I dont think there is any dependency on the DBMS flavor. `select min(x) as y from z;` should work in any SQL database. And the values for{x,y,z}  could differ anyway.